# How to develop skills to speak / write / do presentations on technical topics

Tags: communication

I do not mean English. Just communication. I have this problem in my team that we are often discussing complicated topics, be it face to face, in emails, during meetings or in our issue tracker, and people often find it difficult to stay focused and understand each other.

What are the best resources (books, presentations) on that topic? Is there any way one can learn this quickly?

Comment: Maybe [this][1] helps?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063352/how-can-i-learn-to-express-myself-better

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about business skills, not programming. It _might_ be on-topic at Programmers, but it's likely already been asked there.

Comment: Belongs to Workspace.stackexchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your personal growth:

-take the intiative to be in situations that require this. Join the army! :D But on a more practical note: join a theatre group, start writing/casting a blog, TA some students (officially or not). Simply practicing this often (and getting the immediate feedback through the reaction of other people), you'll start noticing what is more effective and get in the habit of doing it.

-I recommend the book "[On writing well](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0060891548).", William Zinnser. Well written and concise, and short enough that you have the time for it, and most concepts can be applied to communication in general, not just writing.

Note that even though it is quite easy to understand the concepts, this is very much a matter of charachter, so it'll take a while for your effort to become habit. Worth it though.

Are you also looking for ideas for your current situation, or just resources?